# How do you want to open this file

Tags: winapi, registry

[image]

In the above where is the application name populated from?

Scenario, a 32 and 64 bit application opening the same extension and the dialog shows 2 options of the same name.

Have obviously tried different .exe names and different FileDescription, InternalName and OriginalFilename in the application resource but this has no effect on the dialog albeit only doing this after noticing the problem.

Is it the case that there is some sort of caching going on and if so how to clear it programmatically?

Comment: Could this be the [ProductName property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370857.aspx) from the MSI installer?

Comment: I think it could be but after rebuilding the project with a x64 prefix the dialog still shows both version names as the same.